How to Interact with solana Programs?
I am beginner with Solana chain, Learning things compared to EVM based blockchain. I want to know one thing is like how can we interact with Solana program(contract),though i know we can use Solana/web3js library but how can i know that we are calling the specific function of Solana program, i want to give user a specific conditions based on that specific program function will be called as in EVM we can easily call specific function through ABI and we know what is getting called. How to know this in Solana based chain, any simplified documentation will also preferred.

On Solana most programs have an IDL which is a json representation of the program that can be used to generate clients in different languages.
The js types are generated automatically when building an anchor program in the target folder.
Then you can use it similar to this:
var program = new Program(programId, IDL, {})'

let txHash = await pg.program.methods
  .moveRight()
  .accounts({
    gameDataAccount: globalLevel1GameDataAccount,
  })
  .signers([pg.wallet.keypair])
  .rpc();

console.log(`Use 'solana confirm -v ${txHash}' to see the logs`);
await pg.connection.confirmTransaction(txHash);

For C# or Unity you can use the Anchor gen tool:
dotnet tool install Solana.Unity.Anchor.Tool
dotnet anchorgen -i idl/file.json -o src/ProgramCode.cs

https://solanacookbook.com/gaming/porting-anchor-to-unity.html#generating-the-client
This IDL can also be uploaded on chain so that everyone can use it:
anchor idl init 

You can find the docs here:
https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli
